# Click a Button Without ID in iFrame Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

Basically, I am trying to get this script to start agar.io without me having to press the actual button. Agar.io is in a different domain and the button doesn't have an id. I am a n00b with Javascript. The alternative is running `return false;` into the `iframe` code. How can I do either of these?

GOAL: opening the page and bypassing the start button all together

```
<html>

<iframe id ='iframe' src='http://agar.io/#7LLJZ'  width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>


</html>
```

live code: [oliverleopold.com/ughh.php](http://oliverleopold.com/ughh.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything if the iframe is not on the same domain. Search for "same origin" security restrictions.

Comment: The only way to do such things if the site provide means to do it, such as an url parameters that would trigger a script inside their site that clicks the button, or using a technique called CORS (which is over my head), or if you had a browser plugin with elevated rights, which is how firebug seems to be able to do things inside an iframe.